# Burninate the "missing" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta-tags, burninate-request

[missing](/questions/tagged/missing) : <strike>200</strike> 323 questions

I'd argue it's not really an informative tag.

Comment: The tag description is absolutely fitting for the tag, given that it is, ummm, missing ;)

Comment: @Gordon The tag description could point to a 404 page. I'd be okay with that.

Comment: -1 (sorry) because I think it's quite descriptive when used appropriately.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Other banned tags are also descriptive. Problem, error, etc. I'm sure when used appropriately they were quite descriptive. Yet they are banned because they don't actually add substance and are too general to make search useful.

Comment: @MPelletier I see your point if the tag is used by itself.  Perhaps `[missing-x]` tags would be better?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't mean to be obstinate, but I see tags as either categories or domains of expertise. I don't see [tag:missing] or specification thereof as viable.

Comment: But thank you for the suggestion. It made me think that perhaps some questions in the [tag:missing] tag are for other sites. Missing files, for example, would tend to be something with installation, so for SuperUser.

Comment: Please be obstinate if you wish; I would defend my own position. :-)  I admit I don't have any really concrete examples, but I could see e.g. "[database] [missing-data]" as being important.

Comment: Good point regarding SuperUser.  As I was struggling to think of an example, missing-files came to mind first, but I thought just as you did, that is not likely programming related.  It could be helpful to keep such a tag in the system just to find those posts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard whenever it's descriptive, it could be put in a question title to serve its purpose. I mean... who's going to look for questions regarding [missing] things? Concrete examples, maybe, [java][filenotfoundexception], but not [missing] in general.

Comment: @Tom et al, I have gained more experience with tags as a Mathematica.SE pro-tem moderator since I wrote these comments.  I now agree that **[missing]** is not a helpful tag and that descriptive titles would serve the purpose better than any seemingly valid use of the tag.  +2 (downvote reversed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Burninated.]

Not blacklisted yet due to the low volume, but probably a good candidate.

Answer (score 4):

Another sign that the "missing" tag is not considered valuable on stackoverflow.com: It is **not used by experienced users**; the users who asked the [15 newest questions tagged with "missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/missing?sort=newest&pagesize=15) have *median* reputation of 6 (at the time of writing this).